# Trying to get that tube sound from a gainclone amp

Tags: amplifiers, guitar-effects, electronics

A Gainclone chip amp makes for a nice benchmark/monitor amp. How can I add controllable even order harmonic distortion to one?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to actually do with it. If you reword the question to be a little more pointed I think we could possible give some guidance. It's a bit like asking "Is there any sense in painting my lawnmower pink?" ;)

Comment: Good question, but certainly better suited for [electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Use a modeler like the Boss GT-10, Digitech RP500 or the Vox Tonelab to get a decent tube sound.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that you can't. The reason these are so cheap and simple is that there aren't a lot of configurable parts and sadly you are stuck with odd harmonics if you overdrive the LM 3886.

As JimR said, you'll need to use a valve overdrive in your signal path if you do want that sound.